# $\epsilon < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$ implies that: $\epsilon \leq \frac{a+c}{b+d}$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$  Let $\epsilon < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$ Does this imply that: $\epsilon \leq \frac{a+c}{b+d}$?

Answer (score 10):

More generally, you can show that if $\frac a b < \frac c d$ then:$$\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{a+c}{b+d}\leq \frac c d$$

Comment: The last fraction should be $\frac c d$ right?

Comment: I fixed the typo that mathguy pointed out. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: No problem, and thanks! @Nameless

Answer (score 6):

Hint:
$$\epsilon\le \frac{a+c}{b+d}\iff b\epsilon+d\epsilon \le a+c$$
Because $\epsilon < \frac{a}{b}$ and $\epsilon< \frac{c}{d}$,... (you don't actually need that $\frac ab<\frac cd$ this way)

Comment: Indeed $\cfrac {a+c}{b+d}$ is symmetrical in the two terms, so the inequality must also work if $\frac c d < \frac a b$

Comment: Off course, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\dfrac{a}{b}\lt \dfrac{c}{d}$, where $b$ and $d$ are positive real numbers. Then
$$\frac{a}{b}\lt \frac{a+c}{b+d}\lt \frac{c}{d}.$$

We prove the half of the above result that you **do not** need, that $\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}\lt \dfrac{c}{d}$.

A natural approach is to consider the difference $\dfrac{c}{d}-\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$, which simplifies to $\dfrac{bc-ad}{d(b+d)}$. The denominator is positive. And since $\dfrac{c}{d}-\dfrac{a}{b}\gt 0$, the numerator is positive.

**Remark:** You might be interested in other properties of the [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 1):

More generally, 
if $\epsilon < a/b$ and
$\epsilon < c/d$,
where $a, b, c, d$ are positive reals,
then
$\epsilon < (r a+s c)/(r b + s d)$,
where $r$ and $s$ are any positive reals.

Proof:
$\epsilon < (r a+s c)/(r b + s d)$
$\iff$
$\epsilon(r b + s d) < r a+s c$
$\iff$
$r(a-\epsilon b) > s(d \epsilon - c)$
which is true because
 the left side is positive
and the right side is negative.

The reverse inequality is also true,
but $\epsilon$ likes being less than other values
and is uncomfortable when asked to be greater.